# How to Show multiple addresses on a single Map using BingMap services + C#.net

Tags: c#

I'm trying to migrate from MapPoint services to BingMap services for showing Maps on my C#.Net web application. I would like to get the BingMap equivalent of `

- MapPointService.Location[]
- MapPointService.LatLong[]
- MapPointService.MapViewRepresentations
- MapPointService.Pushpin[]
- MapPointService.ViewByBoundingRectangle[]

Answer (score 0):

The [BingMap API documents](http://www.microsoft.com/maps/developers/web.aspx) are a great place to start. Have a read through those, and post again if you have any specific problems, or you can't find something.

Comment: Chris,I have gone to the link mentioned by you but I'm unable to get a place which relates the MapPoint classes to BingMap API classes. Can you help on it.